# How to use Dismissible on a Card object

Tags: widget, dart, flutter

If I have a Card object, how can I use the Dismissable widget on top of that so when the user swipe the card it executes an onDismissed function, I tried the following example but it asks for an identifier for the key:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Dismissible(
    child:  new Card(
//some code

    ),
     key:/*how this works*/
); 
    }
```

is this doable by any mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [docs](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Dismissible-class.html) a Dismissible needs a key to distinguish it from the other Dismissibles.

> If the Dismissible is a list item, it must have a key that distinguishes it from the other items and its onDismissed callback must remove the item from the list.

For my first Todo-App I used [ObjectKey](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ObjectKey-class.html) for that purpose:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Dismissible(
        child:  new Card(
            //some code
        ),
        key: new ObjectKey(widget.todo) 
    ); 
}
```

Does that help you? You should be able to use other [Keys](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Key-class.html) as long as they uniquely identify the Dismissible.